# Angular- mat file upload progress percentage not showing

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my project I am using mat file upload to upload a single/multiple file and it is working fine but the progress percentage and progress percentage bar is not working.
If I clear the cache of browser I am able to see progress of file upload but before every upload I cannot clear the cache everytime. Please help me out.
I took reference from -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materia-file-upload?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materia-file-upload?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts*

This code which I am using in my project